# Using boto3/MQ to list queues on a MQ broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, python-3.7

I've tested the methods listed here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mq.html, but none return the actual queues running on the broker.

Is there a way to list the queues running on a broker using Boto3?

I'd like to get the queues so I can programmatically create dashboards e.g.

```
Region ap-southeast-2
Namespace AWS/AmazonMQ
Metric name MessageUnacknowledgedCount
Broker mybroker
VirtualHost /
Queue default
```

Comment: Probably you have to use MQ native API for that. Not boto3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not recommending this but it works in this situation.  So there was no direct access to MQ so it wasn't possible to query it directly.  Instead, I queried the Cloudwatch API to obtain the queue names e.g.

```
client = conn.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.list_metrics(
        MetricName = "MessageUnacknowledgedCount",
        Namespace='AWS/AmazonMQ',
        Dimensions=[
            {"Name": "Broker", "Value": "my-mq-instance"},
        ],
    )
    
#Don't include queue names that match this pattern.
pattern = re.compile(r'celery@.*\.celery\.pidbox$')

queue_names = [
        dimension['Value']
        for metric in response['Metrics']
        for dimension in metric['Dimensions']
        if dimension['Name'] == 'Queue' and not pattern.match(dimension['Value'])
        and not dimension['Value'].endswith('dead_letter')
        and not dimension['Value'].startswith('celeryev')
    ]
```